# Recreating a visualization

Tags: r, meta

I am very new to R (1 week). I would like to recreate the following graphic for the attached dataset.

```
Date        Rev
1/31/2013   536209
4/30/2013   559175
7/31/2013   535081
10/31/2013  529595
1/31/2014   530919
4/30/2014   518588
7/31/2014   382156
10/31/2014  336705
1/31/2015   326286
```

[image]

I found a code I was attempting to revise for my situation but am having no success.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
rowseq <- seq(nrow(fp),1)
    par(mai=c(1,0,0,0))
    plot(fp$Rev, rowseq, pch=15,
        xlim=c(-10,12), ylim=c(0,7),
        xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
        bty='n')
    axis(1, seq(??,??,by=50000), cex.axis=.5)

    segments(1,-1,1,6.25, lty=3)
    segments(fp$Date, rowseq)

    text(-5,6.5, "Date", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
    t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(fp$Date), format(fp$Date,big.mark=","), '')
    text(-3, rowseq, t2, cex=.75, pos=2)

text(-1,6.5, "Rev", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t3 <- ifelse(!is.na(fp$Rev), with(fp, paste(Rev)
text(3,rowseq, t3, cex=.75, pos=4)
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you get stuck somewhere? This doesn't sound like a question so much as a demand for someone else to do the work for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.

Comment: Definitely not a demand. I apologize if it came across that way. I am very new to R. I have attempted tweaking code I found for a forest plot. However, all of the plots involved numerous variables and I was not having any success. I was working with a code. I will add to my question.

Comment: Then include what code you've tried and describe clearly where you are having trouble. The best questions show that the asker has made some effort to answer the question themselves. Feel free to edit your post to make that clear.

Comment: Where I am getting hung up is I only have two variables. All of the examples I've found have at least 4.  So, adjusting to my data, which is not reflective of a ratio and does not include highs and lows is where I'm having a problem.  I will locate a visualization (as in the example above) but then I can't locate code which is close to this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame named `dd`, your sample plot looks pretty close to something like this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd) + 
   geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=Rev, y=Date, yend=Date)) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=Rev, y=Date), size=4) +
   xlab("Rev")
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to put a `library(ggplot2)` at the start of the code, since OP's original attempt was using base plotting functions.

Comment: Thank you so much, MrFlick and @thelatemail. This is exactly what I was attempting to depict. One additional question, please. When I use an as.date command to convert the date and then plot, R doesn't show every date. Can this be corrected with a p+scale function? Would this also enable the Rev numbers on the x axis show?       fp$Date1 <- as.Date(fp$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"); fp$Date1

Comment: fp$Date1 <- as.Date(fp$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"); fp$Date1
    ggplot(fp) + 
       geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=Rev, y=Date, yend=Date1)) + 
       geom_point(aes(x=Rev, y=Date1), size=4) +
       xlab("Rev")

Comment: If you want a line for every date, it's better to treat them as factors rather than dates in the plot. So instead of `y=Date1`, do `y=factor(Date1)` in the `aes()` parts (be sure to change them all).

Comment: @MrFlick , one more question, please. Do you know of a way to reverse the order of the dates in the output? I have used 
    fp<-fp[order(as.Date(fp$Date1, format="%d/%m/%Y"),        decreasing=TRUE),] which changed the order of the dataset prior to plotting. However, once plotted, it was still in the original order.